# Can we hide/unhide measure column dynamically in tableau without creating multiple sheets?

Tags: tableau-api

Can we hide/unhide measure column dynamically in tableau without creating multiple sheets? Also when we unhide the measure field,column name should also disappear? I am working on Tableau version 10.4

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways -

1. You can create a measure names set and use it (include all the measure you would like to see in your table).
2. you can pivot your data and can make your own measure name and value.

I am not sure what you meant in the second half of your problem statement. Try to provide data table or screenshot of your problem, that way it would be easier to understand.

Besides, I would suggest you to use tableau community forums to look for such answers.